# Android App SSL Decryption

Tags: android, ssl, https, encryption

i am using an android app for chatting which sends an HTTPS request for specific functions , is it possible to read the "readable-decrypted" packet which is being sent by the app ?

I've tried Setting up a proxy using Fiddler and ProxyDROID but it only showed me the results of the Web Broweser not the Apps

Sniffing packets using Shark will an encrypted packets

Edit:
i used Fiddler to monitor the packets , however , due SSL being invalid it doesnt trust it and do not make a connection .. how can i bypass certificate validation check?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question lacks detail. What did you try so far, what was the result? Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Use the technique given here - http://myhowto.org/java/81-intercepting-and-decrypting-ssl-communications-between-android-phone-and-3rd-party-server/

Answer (score 2):

You can decrypt some (if using RSA keys) SSL/TLS traffic with Wireshark if it's compiled a certain way and you have the private key.

From http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL:

> If Wireshark is compiled with SSL decryption support, there will be a
>   new option in the preferences for SSL. This only works for RSA key
>   exchange if the RSA keys can be provided. If the key entry option is
>   absent - then verify if your Wireshark is linked against the required
>   GnuTLS library. This can be done with  wireshark -v . The output
>   should include GnuTLS and GCrypt. If you see without GnuTLS, without
>   Gcrypt, then you will need reconfigure with --with-gnutls, recompile
>   and reinstall..

Comment: unfortunately i dont have the private key , so i can't use wireshark

Comment: @ahmed - If you do not have the private key then you will be unable to decrypt the encrypted data.